# Angular5 + Openlayers4 Add Marker or pop up to lat lon

Tags: angular5, openlayers, marker

I am trying to add a marker or a pop up on the map a soon as a user clicks a button.

I am doing something wrong but really dont know what. You can see my code on the following link:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nvdufp

Does someone know how this works?

Thx a lot

Comment: Your code throws exceptions and does not load

Comment: @dube this is because it doesnt load the ol package if your run it local it will work

Comment: Sorry but I (and probably others) am not spending time on getting it to run